# Weird Xcode autocomplete

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode7.3

I've updated my Xcode yesterday to version 7.3 and since then I got a really strange autocomplete (marked text, case sensitive etc.):

[image]

Is it something of the new version? Can I turn it off and use the classic autocomplete of Xcode?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a new autocomplete in the new Xcode version. It uses fuzzy matching to provide suggestions. I haven't found a way to turn it off, but give it a shot. The old autocomplete is absolutely dreadful. I used to install a [Fuzzy Autocomplete](https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin) plugin to make it work properly.

In the old days (in case of Objective-C, for instance, but it's the same with Swift), if you wanted to implement

```
- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

you typed `-tableView`, saw all the methods starting with `tableView:`, then you added a colon, and the autocomplete died. Now you can just enter something like `-tv:hfrowatinp`, and you instantly get your method.

It will take a bit of time getting used to, but it's worth it, trust me.